# Simple way to test websocket availability in python

Tags: python, websocket

I am using the following code to test that a local websocket server is running:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/registration/123') as websocket:
        await websocket.send(json_data)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

Is there a simpler way to do this without using asyncio? Something such as:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

conn = websockets.connect('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/registration/123')
conn.send('hello')
```

Basically, I'm just trying to find the simplest way to test to see if my websocket server is listening and receiving messages at a particular url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't `async_to_sync` make this more complex? Why not just create a normal `test_url` function:

```
def test_url(url, data=""):
    async def inner():
        async with websockets.connect(url) as websocket:
            await websocket.send(data)
    return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(inner())

test_url("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/registration/123")
```

Comment: perhaps, I'm new to using async, asncid, and async_to_sync, so learning things now. Is there a difference between what your code does and mine? Or is yours just a cleaner approach?

Comment: @David542 Basically it is just a cleaner approach. But anyway you don't need to depend on `asgiref` lib. To be clear, `async_to_sync` is only a wrapper like this. No magic inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the above by using `async_to_sync`, for example:

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
import websockets

def test_url(url, data=""):
    conn = async_to_sync(websockets.connect)(url)
    async_to_sync(conn.send)(data)


test_url("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/registration/123")
```

Note that the "handshake" will probably not complete here because it needs to be accepted both ways, but the above should enable you to test to make sure that the urls are being routed properly, etc.

Answer (score -1):

if you need to disable cert verification, you can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 


import asyncio
import ssl
import websockets 

def test_url(url, data=""):
    async def inner():
        ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
        ctx.check_hostname = False
        ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
        async with websockets.connect(url, ssl=ctx) as websocket:
            await websocket.send(data)
    return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(inner())

test_url("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/registration/123")
```